# pjsip 2.5.5 build error

Tags: android, android-ndk, pjsip

I'm trying to build pjsip for android with `NDK r13b`.
Standard build like `./configure-android  --with-opus=/home/user/pjsip/pjproject/opus-dev-lib` works perfect. But i need several `TARGET_ABI` and all my tries to do it ends with `configure-android error: compiler not found, please check environment settings (TARGET_ABI, etc)`

Commands as
`TARGET_ABI=armeabi-v7a ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags --with-opus=/home/user/pjsip/pjproject/opus-dev-lib`

`TARGET_ABI=armeabi-v7a APP_PLATFORM=android-21 ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags --with-opus=/home/user/pjsip/pjproject/opus-dev-lib`
return the same error.

I'm search a lot of links but no result.
I know that error is in `configure-android` file and throwing by

```
  if test "x${CC}" = "x" || test ! -e ${CC}; then
      echo "$F error: compiler not found, please check environment
      settings     (TARGET_ABI, etc)"
    exit 1
  fi
```

But i have no idea how to solve it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, i'm finished with build.

Using [Alex Gotev](https://github.com/VoiSmart/pjsip-android-builder) build and modify `config.conf`, `prepare-build-system` and `build` for needed configuration and latest `pjsip` source.
Also i had to use latest `libyuv` from [googlesource](https://chromium.googlesource.com/libyuv/libyuv/) and `NDK r10e`.

**UPDATED**

Using android-ndk-r13 or later use `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9 TARGET_ABI=armeabi-v7a ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags`. At the moment it's able to build pjsip 2.6

Comment: I'm unable to build pjsip 2.6. It is mandatory to use android-ndk-r13? And where do I set the NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9? Thx

Comment: It's not mandatory, `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION` you set in terminal as `TARGET_ABI`

Comment: It's working fine. They've changed the folder structured and thats why the script didn't find the files. Thanks anyway.

Comment: im trying to build PJSIP 2.6 with android-ndk-r17 and getting this error : ../src/pj/ssl_sock_ossl.c:48:10: fatal error: 'openssl/asn1.h' file not found
#include <openssl/asn1.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [output/pjlib-x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0/ssl_sock_ossl.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [libpj-x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0.a] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 1