# Error While building PJSiP in Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, pjsip

When i tried to put this command while building pjsip for android,

TARGET_ABI=armeabi-v7a ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags

This error occured,

compiler not found, please check environment settings (TARGET_ABI, etc)

can somebody give me an explanation.pls

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm sure you've moved on past this by now, but for anyone else who finds this thread:

Just set the `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION` environment variable to `4.9`

This can be done either by doing an export prior to the configure call:

```
export NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9
./configure-android
```

or on the same command line as the configure call:

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9 TARGET_ABI=<whatever> ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags
```

In revision 13+ of the android NDK, the default compiler is Clang instead of GCC. PJSIP 2.6 (newest as of this writing) is not yet updated to parse for the Clang compiler location correctly, so it claims "compiler not found, please check environment settings". Setting the `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION` to `4.9` forces the NDK to use GCC in place of Clang, and then PJSIP will be happy.

According to [the NDK revision history](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/revision_history.html), GCC will be removed in a future release. So if someone reading this is using a version of the NDK where it's been removed (which hasn't happened yet at the time of this writing), you'll need to just downgrade your NDK.

This solution comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40489254/4175444) and the corresponding PJSIP ticket [can be found here](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/ticket/1968).

Comment: I'm using ndk 13b and I've set Tollchaing to 4.9 but I'm still facing the same error ?

Comment: I am using NDK-r16, still facing the same issue. getting same error : compiler not found, please check environment settings (TARGET_ABI, etc

Comment: I am using ndk-18 and facing the same issue. Does anyone found solution?

Answer (score 0):

GCC support has been stopped and has been replaced by Clang.

Try this:

```
export CC="$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -gcc-toolchain $NDK_TOOLCHAIN"

export CXX="$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -gcc-toolchain $NDK_TOOLCHAIN"
```