# android PjSip 2.8 fails building for armeabi-v7a, X86_64 even after using NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9

Tags: android, android-ndk, cross-compiling, pjsip

Trying to build pjsip version 2.8 for android, downloaded from here : http://www.pjsip.org/download.htm

Following below article to build for different ABI archs
https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android

followed 1,2,3 steps for building, i am able to build for `arm64-v8a` but its failing for armeabi-v7a, x86_64.

shows error as

> /root/abcd/android-ndk-r16b/build/core/build-shared-library.mk:23: *** Android NDK: Please correct error. Aborting    .  Stop.
>   NDK_CC :
>   configure-android error: compiler not found, please check environment settings (TARGET_ABI, etc)

I tried below thread solution,but it is'nt working now for many people, show that in the comment.

[Error While building PJSiP in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40594699/error-while-building-pjsip-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i was able to build for different architecture using the Ndk r16 without using NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9

i had followed this article completely.
https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android

issue was that after building for one architecture, lets say **armeabi-v7a**

i was not able to build for another architecture **arm64-v8a**.

Solution was, i have to perform clean up process exactly and perfectly, if cleanup doesn't happens properly, then next build doesn't happens properly

See here-> [link](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android#create-own-app) in detail for the cleanup process
point number -> 4

Comment: I tried directly with armeabi-v7a and I am facing this error like java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed:cannot locate symbol "__aeabi_memclr8" referenced by "/data/app/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so"...